# Python Mechanize timeout issues

Tags: python, timeout, mechanize

I am trying to get the htmltext from nydaily news and other websites, but I can't get mechanize to timeout correctly. When the timeout is .01, it times out immediately, however when the timeout is something more reasonable (1.0), it runs for ~ 2 minutes before giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/monitor.py", line 575, in run
    already_pickled=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/utils/bsdsocket.py", line 24, in write_packet
    sock.send(struct.pack("l", len(sent_data)) + sent_data)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

```py
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()    
url = 'http://www.nydailynews.com/services/feeds'
htmltext= br.open(url,timeout=1.0).read()
print htmltext[:200]
```

Comment: The solution here isn't about tuning the timing out I don't think. If you consider the problem could be affected by a variety of factors. The computer running the code, the latency and speed of the internet connection, the remote host running dynamic code.. If you want this process to be faster, start using greenlets or threads or some way to parallelize the problem so that you can wait for things to sort themselves out. You may be connecting to a host with a slow uplink on the other side of the earth.. More parallel attempts will make it faster, dialing down timeout will make it unreliable

Comment: Yes - I agree that I should run this in parallel. However, I still don't understand why setting the timeout didn't work. The timeout should cut this off after 1 second - right? Or am I misunderstanding the intent of passing this value to the open method?

Answer (score 1):

There's something goofy going on with the way urllib2 is working in general (mechanize uses a fork)

Take a look at this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import urllib2
import sys

def graburl(url,timeout):
    urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=float(timeout))

for i in range(1,30):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        graburl("http://www.cnn.com:443", i)
    except:
        print 'Timeout: ', i, 'Duration: ', time.time() - start
```

When run:

```
Timeout:  1 Duration:  4.45208692551
Timeout:  2 Duration:  8.00451898575
Timeout:  3 Duration:  12.0053498745
Timeout:  4 Duration:  16.0044560432
Timeout:  5 Duration:  20.0762069225
Timeout:  6 Duration:  24.005065918
```

So the actual timeout ends up being 4x the timeout specified.

Note that in this specific case the connection is successful to the socket, but it just can't read the data correctly. (Or the request isn't serviced in a reasonable amount of time...)

If anyone can come up with a good reason why the timeout is multiplied by four I'd be very interested in what causes that.

Tested with python 2.7.5 on OSX Mavericks

Using socket.setdefaulttimeout() doesn't seem to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Those links take a long time to run even in a browser. Within Python I was able to load the subset `http://feeds.nydailynews.com/nydnrss/sports` in about 16 seconds (w/o specifying a timeout).

I think you would need to set the timeout to something even more "reasonable" than one second  to give it a chance to load, and I would choose a more focused feed than the main page where they are all listed. This link of top stories loads successfully for me with `timeout=1`: http://feeds.nydailynews.com/nydnrss